# Gitlab runner does not print output of docker run command

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Is there any way to print `docker run` coomand output on a gitlab runner?

I am running the following:

```
  docker-build:
  # Official docker image.
  image: docker/compose:debian-1.26.2
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - apt update && apt install -y curl
    - docker-compose build
    - docker-compose up -d
    - DB_CONTAINER=`docker ps | grep server | awk '{print $NF}'`
    - until (docker logs $DB_CONTAINER 2>&1 | grep -e ' Running on'); do echo "Waiting for server..."; sleep 1; done # Wait for the DB to be ready
  script:
    - cd tests
    - docker build -t testimg .
    - docker -t -v $PWD/tests_integration_test1.py:/tests_integration_test1.py run testimg pytest tests_integration_test1.py
```

but nothing is printed to the gitlab ci log

Comment: have you tried passing some option `-i` or `-t` (or both) before `run`? Otherwise, could you edit your question to include a [mre]? (e.g. with some `.gitlab-ci.yml` code, given that the surrounding context of your `docker run` command also matters)

Comment: @ErikMD I tried the -i or -t flag before run but it failed, I also edit the question and add all the gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: @chatzich try `docker run -i -t ...` instead of `docker -i -t  run ...`